# Need relative list items to ignore parents and children, and float with siblings

Tags: css, list, drop-down-menu, height

I've been trying to get these list items to float with their siblings, but they automatically create a margin for their children.

These list items must remain position:relative so that the #dropdown div will resize when new children are revealed.

I've tried setting the children to absolute, and using jquery to resize the div with .height(), but it doesnt respond to the height of 'ul'.

Haven't implemented drop-down functionality yet - still trying to get them to sit correctly.

Please help!

Heres my fiddle so far http://jsfiddle.net/63pNN/3/

The menu should look like this when Item1 > ItemA is selected:

Home **Item1** Item2 Item3
**ItemA** ItemB
ItemX ItemY

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a width when using floats and margin's like so:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/63pNN/31/

Comment: the list items must be auto width, because its a CMS and a I dont know how many characters will be in each list item.  Thanks though!

Comment: Then you can specify a min-width instead of width.
Then you can play around with word-wrap and text ellipsis if the string is too long.
Send me a link, let's solve this :)